# Prove that any group is a disjoint union of conjugacy classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

How do I prove that any group is a disjoint union of conjugacy classes?
Any reading reference would also be helpful

Comment: Simply prove that conjugacy is an equivalence relation; the result is then immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation and use the information that a $G$-set is the disjoint union of its orbits under the action.